# How to eliminate specific brew doctor errors?

Tags: homebrew

When I am running brew doctor I am getting the following list of errors.
Is there any way I can eliminate these error reports?
Thank you.

```
    Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
    /usr/local/include/c-client.h
    /usr/local/include/dummy.h
    /usr/local/include/env.h
    /usr/local/include/env_unix.h
    /usr/local/include/fdstring.h
    /usr/local/include/flockcyg.h
    /usr/local/include/flocksim.h
    /usr/local/include/flstring.h
    /usr/local/include/fs.h
    /usr/local/include/ftl.h
    /usr/local/include/imap4r1.h
    /usr/local/include/layout/LayoutEngine.h
    /usr/local/include/layout/LEFontInstance.h
    /usr/local/include/layout/LEGlyphFilter.h
    /usr/local/include/layout/LEGlyphStorage.h
    /usr/local/include/layout/LEInsertionList.h
    /usr/local/include/layout/LELanguages.h
    /usr/local/include/layout/LEScripts.h
    /usr/local/include/layout/LESwaps.h
    /usr/local/include/layout/LETypes.h
    /usr/local/include/layout/loengine.h
    /usr/local/include/layout/ParagraphLayout.h
    /usr/local/include/layout/playout.h
    /usr/local/include/layout/plruns.h
    /usr/local/include/layout/RunArrays.h
    /usr/local/include/linkage.h
    /usr/local/include/mail.h
    /usr/local/include/mcrypt.h
    /usr/local/include/misc.h
    /usr/local/include/netmsg.h
    /usr/local/include/newsrc.h
    /usr/local/include/nl.h
    /usr/local/include/nntp.h
    /usr/local/include/node/eio-emul.h
    /usr/local/include/node/ev-emul.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/eio.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/ev.h
    /usr/local/include/os_a32.h
    /usr/local/include/os_a41.h
    /usr/local/include/os_a52.h
    /usr/local/include/os_aix.h
    /usr/local/include/os_aos.h
    /usr/local/include/os_art.h
    /usr/local/include/os_asv.h
    /usr/local/include/os_aux.h
    /usr/local/include/os_bsd.h
    /usr/local/include/os_bsf.h
    /usr/local/include/os_bsi.h
    /usr/local/include/os_cvx.h
    /usr/local/include/os_cyg.h
    /usr/local/include/os_d-g.h
    /usr/local/include/os_do4.h
    /usr/local/include/os_drs.h
    /usr/local/include/os_dyn.h
    /usr/local/include/os_hpp.h
    /usr/local/include/os_isc.h
    /usr/local/include/os_lnx.h
    /usr/local/include/os_lyn.h
    /usr/local/include/os_mct.h
    /usr/local/include/os_mnt.h
    /usr/local/include/os_nto.h
    /usr/local/include/os_nxt.h
    /usr/local/include/os_os4.h
    /usr/local/include/os_osf.h
    /usr/local/include/os_osx.h
    /usr/local/include/os_ptx.h
    /usr/local/include/os_pyr.h
    /usr/local/include/os_qnx.h
    /usr/local/include/os_s40.h
    /usr/local/include/os_sc5.h
    /usr/local/include/os_sco.h
    /usr/local/include/os_sgi.h
    /usr/local/include/os_shp.h
    /usr/local/include/os_slx.h
    /usr/local/include/os_soln.h
    /usr/local/include/os_solo.h
    /usr/local/include/os_sos.h
    /usr/local/include/os_sua.h
    /usr/local/include/os_sun.h
    /usr/local/include/os_sv2.h
    /usr/local/include/os_sv4.h
    /usr/local/include/os_ult.h
    /usr/local/include/os_vu2.h
    /usr/local/include/osdep.h
    /usr/local/include/php/ext/hash/php_hash_types.h
    /usr/local/include/php/main/logos.h
    /usr/local/include/php/main/php_logos.h
    /usr/local/include/php/TSRM/tsrm_virtual_cwd.h
    /usr/local/include/pseudo.h
    /usr/local/include/rfc822.h
    /usr/local/include/smtp.h
    /usr/local/include/sslio.h
    /usr/local/include/tcp.h
    /usr/local/include/tcp_unix.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/alphaindex.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/appendable.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/basictz.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/bms.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/bmsearch.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/brkiter.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/bytestream.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/bytestrie.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/bytestriebuilder.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/calendar.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/caniter.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/chariter.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/choicfmt.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/coleitr.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/coll.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/colldata.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/curramt.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/currpinf.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/currunit.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/datefmt.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/dbbi.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/dcfmtsym.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/decimfmt.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/docmain.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/dtfmtsym.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/dtintrv.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/dtitvfmt.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/dtitvinf.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/dtptngen.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/dtrule.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/errorcode.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/fieldpos.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/fmtable.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/format.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/fpositer.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/gregocal.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/icudataver.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/icuplug.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/idna.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/localpointer.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/locdspnm.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/locid.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/measfmt.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/measunit.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/measure.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/messagepattern.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/msgfmt.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/normalizer2.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/normlzr.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/numfmt.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/numsys.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/parseerr.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/parsepos.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/platform.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/plurfmt.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/plurrule.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/ptypes.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/putil.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/rbbi.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/rbnf.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/rbtz.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/regex.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/rep.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/resbund.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/schriter.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/search.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/selfmt.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/simpletz.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/smpdtfmt.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/sortkey.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/std_string.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/strenum.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/stringpiece.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/stringtriebuilder.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/stsearch.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/symtable.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/tblcoll.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/timezone.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/tmunit.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/tmutamt.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/tmutfmt.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/translit.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/tzfmt.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/tznames.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/tzrule.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/tztrans.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/ubidi.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/ubrk.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/ucal.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/ucasemap.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/ucat.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/uchar.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/ucharstrie.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/ucharstriebuilder.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/uchriter.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/uclean.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/ucnv.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/ucnv_cb.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/ucnv_err.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/ucnvsel.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/ucol.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/ucoleitr.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/uconfig.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/ucsdet.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/ucurr.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/udat.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/udata.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/udateintervalformat.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/udatpg.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/uenum.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/uidna.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/uiter.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/uldnames.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/uloc.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/ulocdata.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/umachine.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/umisc.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/umsg.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/unifilt.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/unifunct.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/unimatch.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/unirepl.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/uniset.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/unistr.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/unorm.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/unorm2.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/unum.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/uobject.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/upluralrules.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/uregex.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/urename.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/urep.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/ures.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/uscript.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/usearch.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/uset.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/usetiter.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/ushape.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/uspoof.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/usprep.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/ustdio.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/ustream.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/ustring.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/ustringtrie.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/utext.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/utf.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/utf16.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/utf32.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/utf8.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/utf_old.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/utmscale.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/utrace.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/utrans.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/utypes.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/uvernum.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/uversion.h
    /usr/local/include/unicode/vtzone.h
    /usr/local/include/unix.h
    /usr/local/include/utf8.h
    /usr/local/include/utf8aux.h
```

Comment: 1. Did you read the message at the top of your textbox, which says "don't worry if everything seems to be working fine"?  Is everything working fine?  If things are not working fine, please edit the question to clarify what is/isn't working.  If everything is working fine, why do you think there is anything to "fix" or anything that needs to be done?  2. What have you tried?  What research have you done?  3. This question might be better directed to homebrew support forums.  Have you tried asking at Homebrew-specific forums?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you've manually downloaded and compiled something that has dropped files in `/usr/local` (I'm guessing a mail server). If you don't need it you could remove the files it has deposited in `/usr/local`.

At the same time, as the message says this is only a warning, not an error message. The only time you really need to worry about this is if you are having trouble compiling software with brew. If everything is compiling okay then don't worry about it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Is there any way I can find which program installed these files?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way. Just taking a guess from some of the mentioned files it looks like a mail server to me. That's just a guess though.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you installed node.js before. Try this, search in Terminal /usr/local/include and delete all stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

For these types of warnings specifically, you could probably use a custom installation prefix. The homebrew installation instructions ([2016 Apr 3 permalink](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/276a797d37fa057f935ba671bca04163389046f1/share/doc/homebrew/Installation.md)) say you can do that, but warn against it. In practice I've heard that issues are quite rarely encountered.